# Which hooks are provided in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-events

Officially only `$.cssHooks` is documented in [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/), and `$.valHooks` is mentioned in a sentence for a workaround to a known issue in [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

I wonder how many hooks are there in jQuery besides of these 2, and should we use `$.valHooks` in our plugin development? If so, I think it should be documented as a dedicated topic instead of one-sentence only.

Comment: +1 came to know new thing in jquery

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't rely on undocumented features because their behavior might be unpredictable and can change at any time without notice in future versions.

Comment: @Juhana: Agree. However, seems `$.valHooks` is now used by some plugins to change the behavior of `.val()`. And I really think it's a good hook somehow.

Comment: There are *a lot* of hooks in the library: `$.attrHooks`, `$.propHooks`, `$.event.fixHooks`, `$.event.keyHooks`, `$.event.mouseHooks`, and so on. You may want to refer to the source code about these.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 8 different types of exposed hooks.

There is one more for internal usage only (which is exposed) - `jQuery._queueHooks()`.

There are also two other hooks: `nodeHook` and `boolHook` which are used internally and their functionality is basically embedded into `jQuery.attrHooks` and `jQuery.valHooks`.

Here are the important ones:

- **`jQuery.attrHooks`**

  - Setting the type on a `radio` input after the value resets the value in IE6-9.
  - Set `contenteditable` to false on removals ([Bug #10429](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10429)).
  - Set width and height to auto instead of 0 on empty string ([Bug #8150](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8150))
  - [Some attributes require a special call on IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536429%28VS.85%29.aspx) - `href`, `src`, `width` and `height`.
  - Return `undefined` in the case of empty string for the `style` attribute.
  - Fix get/set for the `value` property in old IE
  - When reading attribute values if no hook is defined it uses either `boolHook` or `nodeHook` (which is the same as `jQuery.valHooks.button`).
  - Could be used to attach additional hooks when getting/setting an attribute of an element.
- **`jQuery.propHooks`**

  - `href`/`src` properties should get the full normalized URL ([Bug #10299](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10299), [Bug #12915](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12915)).
  - Fix for "Safari mis-reports the default selected property of an option".
  - Could be used to attach additional hooks when getting/setting a property of an element.
- **`jQuery.Tween.propHooks`**

  `jQuery.Tween` is used for animations and such.

  - Fix for `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` in IE8 - will be removed in jQuery 2.0.
  - Other animation stuff.
- **`jQuery.cssHooks`**

  Add in style property hooks for overriding the default behavior of getting and setting a style property.

  - Fix for getting/setting the value of the CSS property `opacity`.
  - Fix for getting `witdth` and `height` depending on the `display` property.
  - Fix for setting `width` and `height` depending on the `box-sizing` property.
  - Fix for getting margin-right.
  - Fix for [Webkit Bug #29084](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29084) - `getComputedStyle` returns percent when specified for top/left/bottom/right
  - Used in `jQuery.fn.animate` to expand specified style properties like `margin`, `padding` and `border`.
  - Used in other various `jQuery.fn.animate` related stuff.
  - Setting various background CSS properties to `inherit` is achieved without using `jQuery.cssHooks`, because it is shorter this way.
  - Could be used to attach additional hooks when getting/setting an individual style property of an element.
- **`jQuery.valHooks`**

  - Fixes a Blackberry 4.7 bug for `option` elements ([Bug #6932](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6932)).
  - Used for reading selected value for `select` elements.
  - Fixes reading some properties of the `button` element - `id`, `name` and `coords`. The same as `nodeHook` (see above).
  - Fixes the incompatibility on checking `radio` and `checkbox` inputs between Webkit and others.
  - Could be used to attach additional hooks when getting/setting the value of an input element.
- **`jQuery.event.fixHooks`**

  A holder for `jQuery.event.mouseHooks` and `jQuery.event.keyHooks` which require fixing and normalizing based on the support of the current browser.
- **`jQuery.event.mouseHooks`**

  - Used to transfer some properties from the original `MouseEvent` to the jQuery event object.
  - Normalizes `event.which` (which mouse button was used) accross browsers, because `event.button` is not normalized.
  - Calculates `pageX`, `pageY`, `clientX`, `clientY` and others if missing and set them to the jQuery event object.
- **`jQuery.event.keyHooks`**

  - Used to transfer some properties from the original `KeyboardEvent` to the jQuery event object.
  - Normalizes `event.which` (the character code of the button which was pressed) across browsers. In the original event it could be `char`, `charCode`, `key` or `keyCode`.

From the jQuery 1.9.1 source.

Comment: Thank you very much for listing all such hooks. I think I need to read the jQuery src code throughout for each.