# what is $.event.fixHooks in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I found this piece of code in [jquery.mousewheel.js](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/blob/master/jquery.mousewheel.js)

My question is what is $.event.fixHooks？Where can I find document for it?  I can't find any useful document to explain usage.

```
var toFix  = ['wheel', 'mousewheel', 'DOMMouseScroll', 'MozMousePixelScroll'],
    toBind = ( 'onwheel' in document || document.documentMode >= 9 ) ?
                ['wheel'] : ['mousewheel', 'DomMouseScroll', 'MozMousePixelScroll'],
    slice  = Array.prototype.slice,
    nullLowestDeltaTimeout, lowestDelta;

if ( $.event.fixHooks ) {
    for ( var i = toFix.length; i; ) {
        $.event.fixHooks[ toFix[--i] ] = $.event.mouseHooks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About `Event.fixHooks`:

> The fixHooks interface provides a per-event-type way to extend or
>   normalize the event object that jQuery creates when it processes a
>   native browser event. A fixHooks entry is an object that has two
>   properties, each being optional:
>
> **props**: Array: Strings representing properties that should be copied from the browser's event object to the jQuery event object. If
>   omitted, no additional properties are copied beyond the standard ones
>   that jQuery copies and normalizes (e.g. event.target and
>   event.relatedTarget).
>
> filter: Function( event, originalEvent ): jQuery calls this function
>   after it constructs the jQuery.Event object, copies standard
>   properties from jQuery.event.props, and copies the fixHooks-specific
>   props (if any) specified above. The function can create new properties
>   on the event object or modify existing ones. The second argument is
>   the browser's native event object, which is also available in
>   event.originalEvent.
>
> Note that for all events, the browser's native event object is
>   available in event.originalEvent; if the jQuery event handler examines
>   the properties there instead of jQuery's normalized event object,
>   there is no need to create a fixHooks entry to copy or modify the
>   properties.
>
> For example, to set a hook for the "drop" event that copies the
>   dataTransfer property, assign an object to jQuery.event.fixHooks.drop:

```
jQuery.event.fixHooks.drop = {
    props: [ "dataTransfer" ]
};
```

> Since fixHooks is an advanced feature and rarely used externally,
>   jQuery does not include code or interfaces to deal with conflict
>   resolution. If there is a chance that some other code may be assigning
>   fixHooks to the same events, the code should check for an existing
>   hook and take appropriate measures. A simple solution might look like
>   this:

```
if ( jQuery.event.fixHooks.drop ) {
    throw new Error( "Someone else took the jQuery.event.fixHooks.drop hook!" );
}

jQuery.event.fixHooks.drop = {
    props: [ "dataTransfer" ]
};
```

**ABout this code**

```
if ( $.event.fixHooks ) {
    for ( var i = toFix.length; i; ) {
        $.event.fixHooks[ toFix[--i] ] = $.event.mouseHooks;
    }
}
```

basically, this is extending/normalizing `'wheel', 'mousewheel', 'DOMMouseScroll', 'MozMousePixelScroll'` events. setting their value to `$.event.mouseHooks`. Now you might ask what does this `event.mouseHooks` do?

jQuery.event.mouseHooks is

- Used to transfer some properties from the original MouseEvent to the
  jQuery event object.
- Normalizes `event.which` (which mouse button was used) across browsers, because `event.button` is not normalized.
- Calculates `pageX`, `pageY`, `clientX`, `clientY` and others if missing and
  set them to the jQuery event object

Hope it helps

References:

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/
- [Which hooks are provided in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494498/which-hooks-are-provided-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Read [jQuery Event Extensions](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/) .

> Note: available jQuery 1.7+

Answer (score 0):

It's an [`Event Extensions`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/).

```
You need to use at least jQuery 1.7+

There is no fixHooks in jQuery 1.6.2.
```